# iOS tableView with time at the left

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, calendar, custom-cell

I'm building an iOS app that would benefit from having the time from say 07:00 to 16:00 (specified by user) on the left of a UITableViewCell like this:

[image]

What would be the best approach for such a behaviour, including the possibility of a colored rectangle over several cells? I imagine you would design a custom cell but it's the colored rectangle (appointments in the iOS calendar) logic that I'm not sure how to go about as it stretches over several cells.

Could someone point me in the right direction, give any links or something to kick me off? Just an explanation of how one would go about this is helpful.

Thanks alot!
Erik

Comment: that doesn't look like left of table view. It is on top of the table view right?

Comment: @T_77 My best guess is that it's a custom designed cell with the separators just further to the right so on top, yes

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look into UICollectionView, with provides powerful layout apis for this kind of problem than UITableView.

There are a lot to dig into though.

Some of these materials maybe helpful to you:

1. http://www.objc.io/issue-3/collection-view-layouts.html
2. https://github.com/erichoracek/MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout

Comment: I see, thanks! The bottom link looks the most promising, especially in terms of design. I'm having a hard time getting started though, there's a lot of code and I just don't know how to begin with it

Comment: There's import build errors and no helpful tutorial