# iOS 7 Content stretches over several UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Follow-up question to my other question ["iOS tableView with time at left"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653219/ios-tableview-with-time-at-the-left/29655748#29655748)

I'm trying to implement a calendar like application like this using [this project found at GitHub](https://github.com/erichoracek/MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout)

[image]

I've tried to create a ViewController with a CollectionView and also a CollectionViewController, then import "MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout" header and implementation file and setting them as a custom layout for the CollectionView.

**Trying to build from the workspace file gives me this error:**

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

**Trying to build from the Xcode project file gives me this error along with the above one:**

RestKit.h file not found

What is the correct way to start using this project using a simple structure for every item?

I can't seem to find any tutorial or similar with instructions on how to get started.

My question is as follows: **Can someone help me explain how I can get started with this, without using the SeatGeek API?**

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Did you try following their CocoaPods documentation?

Comment: They have an Example Project in their cloned repo that you could work with.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a couple problems here: What's going on with the example first, then why it's going under your navigation stuff second.

I'll start with the first issue.

His example is using Cocoapods, and it seems like he attempted to attach the completed xcworkspace to make it easier, but it didn't work for me either.

I'd suggest installing [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/) and running the pod install yourself. All the instructions for how to do that should be in that link.

After doing that, the thing still wouldn't compile because some pod is attempting to set an enum to something that isn't a compile time constant. Just go ahead and change the enum values to constants (should be 1000, 750, 250, 50 respectively for the missing values) for the sake of getting the example running. If you were using pods in production code, you would NEVER want to do this, but since this is an example utilizing outdated pods, just take the path of least resistance here.

As far as the content being under the navigation bar, you're probably going to have to muck about with setting the CollectionView's `contentInsets`. You could also just pin the CollectionView to be under that header bit you have there with autolayout or frames.

Comment: I made it build and run now doing what you said, works good like that - but I have no idea on how to bring this over to a new project. There are a ton of classes, no storyboard file for design and overall hard to understand. Have you used it in one of your projects? Or do you know of a similar project that looks the same as the middle part of the iOS calendar app, (excluding the navigationbar and toolbar as I've got my own) that is more clear and easier to use?

Comment: So, the easiest way to implement that project would be to create a Podfile yourself for your own project. You just create a file with the pods you want (just like their example) and run pod install. The github page for that project has instructions on installing via Cocoapods and since you've already got that part working, using that to install for your project should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Beyond that, I haven't used this project at all or anything like it really, but the answer to the question of why the header view is stretching over the content should be solvable via what I mentioned in my response. Glancing at the documentation, it seems like what is provided is mostly just a flow layout for a UICollectionView, but you probably have to provide the cells themselves. There's a list of what cells are expected in the readme. For anything else, I'd just reference the code in the example and mimic whatever you need from that.

Comment: Yeah, I'll see if I can get anything out of it, looks kinda dark atm. I haven't created any ViewControllers or done much design without interface builder so I don't get much overview, like what I should change and how to interact with it, like didSelectRowInIndexPath and similar in tableViews

Comment: I'm finding this very frustrating. Why use cocoapods for an example project? Just seems to make everything so much harder. I can't get it to work in any other project than the example I downloaded. Please see my question update

Comment: Not sure why they'd use Cocoapods for the example, but it shouldn't have any effect on your project. If you want to use this library, Cocoapods is probably the way to go by simply putting ```pod 'MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout'``` in a podfile and running it. If that isn't working, there's not enough information for me to tell you why not.

Comment: Say I made that work, there's still a lot to dig into and I find this very hard without any tutorial or explanation. I really need a ViewController like this but I don't understand that library